# Proof that objects are colimits of generators

Tags: ct.category-theory

Suppose $\mathcal{C}$ is a category with small colimits, and $G \in \mathrm{Ob}(\mathcal{C})$ is a strong generator. (This means that $f: X \to Y$ is an isomorphism iff $f_{*}: \mathrm{Hom}(G,X) \to \mathrm{Hom}(G,Y)$ is a bijection.)

> How does one prove that every object $X$ is a colimit of copies of $G$ (i.e., a quotient of coproducts of $G$)?

I think $X \simeq \mathop{\mathrm{colim}}_{G \to X} G$. I can see there is a natural map $e: \mathop{\mathrm{colim}}_{G \to X} \to X$, and that the induced map $e_{*}: Hom(G,\mathop{\mathrm{colim}}_{G \to X}) \to Hom(G, X)$ is surjective, but I cannot see that it map is injective.

Comment: I know the following definition of a generator (from Mac Lane's book): For every distinct $f,g : X \to Y$, there is some $h : G \to X$ such that $fh, gh$ are also distinct. I doubt that this is equivalent to your one.

Comment: What you called a "generator" is usually called a *strong generator*.  Although a few people do confusingly call it merely a "generator," and instead say "separator" for the notion mentioned by Martin (which is what is more commonly called a "generator").


Comment: For what is commonly called a generator (i.e., what Martin mentions in his comment), the result fails: In Top a point is a generator, but colimits of points are just discrete spaces.

Comment: I don't understand what the colimit in the last paragraph is indexed over. Is it the _set_ Hom(G,X)? In that case it seems to me you could only mean the coproduct, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: The colimit is taken over the slice category as $$\varinjlim_{f\in(G\downarrow X)}s(f)$$ where $s$ is the canonical functor $(G\downarrow X)\to C$ sending every object to its source (in this case G) and every commutative triangle to the corresponding morphism in $C$.  Joey's notation is a bit too abusive for my tastes, but I understood what he meant.

Comment: If that's what is meant, then the statement is false.  In the category of compact Hausdorff spaces, the terminal object is a strong generator.  But since it has no endomorphisms, that slice category is discrete, so the colimit is just the coproduct of 1 over the set Hom(1,X), and this is the Stone-Cech compactification of the underlying set of X -- generally not the same as X.

Comment: Compact Hausdorff isn't closed under colimits...

Comment: Sorry, Joey -- compact Hausdorff spaces are a cocomplete category. This is well-known. (You are right however that colimits there are not computed as they would be in $Top$.) I don't think however the question has been totally settled by Mike's example, because one can still present a compact Hausdorff space as a colimit of a diagram consisting totally of 1's (essentially because compact Hausdorff spaces are monadic over sets). 

Comment: Ditto Mike's last sentence. The last example I tried looking at was where $G$ is the 2-dimensional oriental in the category 2-Cat, which I'm pretty sure is not dense (because Street's nerve functor is not full on 2-Cat). 


Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think there are actually *three* possible things that you might be asking, but the answer to all of them is no.  Suppose that G is a strong generator in a cocomplete category C.  Then you can ask:

1. Is every object X of C the colimit of G over the canonical diagram of shape $(G\downarrow X)$?  (If so, then G is called *dense* in C.)
2. Is every object *some* colimit of a diagram all of whose vertices are G?  (If so, then G is called *colimit-dense* in C.)
3. Is C the smallest subcategory of itself containing G and closed under colimits?  (If so, then G is a *colimit-generator* of C.)

The category of compact Hausdorff spaces is a counterexample to the first two.  It is monadic over Set (the monad is the ultrafilter monad, aka Stone-Cech compactification of the discrete topology), and hence cocomplete, and the one-point space is a strong generator.  But any colimit of a diagram consisting entirely of 1-point spaces must be in the image of the free functor from Set (the one-point space being its own Stone-Cech compactification), and hence (since that functor is a left adjoint and preserves colimits) must be the free object on some set.  However, not every compact Hausdorff space is the Stone-Cech compactification of a discrete set.

As Todd pointed out in the comments, though, CptHaus is the colimit-closure of the one-point space, since every object is a coequalizer of maps between free ones (because the category is monadic over Set); thus it isn't a counterexample to the third question.  Counterexamples to the third question are actually much harder to come by, and in fact if you assume additionally that C has finite limits and is "extremally well-copowered", then it is true that any strong generator is a colimit-generator.  I think there's a proof of this somewhere in Kelly's book "Basic concepts of enriched category theory," and a brief version can be found [here](https://home.sandiego.edu/~shulman/papers/generators.pdf).  However, without these assumptions, one can cook up ugly and contrived counterexamples, such as example 4.3 in the paper "Total categories and solid functors" by Borger and Tholen.

Comment: +1 Nice answer, Mike. Now I don't have to struggle with this any more! :-) 

Answer (score 1):

See cor. 4.4 in "Strong regular and dense generators" Tholen , Borger:

http://www.numdam.org/numdam-bin/fitem?id=CTGDC_1991__32_3_257_0